# file not downloading on ajax post response .net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, filecontentresult

i am facing problem on file response , its not downloading file, please check following code containing controller method and Ajax post call,

the object there is to input an excel file from user on the form, read and calculate the data on conditions and make results accordingly and return the byte array in file response to browser.

everything working smooth, the input file working fine , data reading working fine, just issue there on the response, its not showing any error and pass through all code without error with file not downloading.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadCallingDocument(UploadCallingViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                FormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files as FormFileCollection;
                {
                    IFormFile file = files[0];
                    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                            var result = await importExportFileManager.KeepAndShareFileAsync(stream);
                            return File(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Summarized_KeepAndShare_File.xlsx");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //to create error notification
            }
            return RedirectToAction("UploadCalling");
        }

 
$('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        // Doing some loading gif stuff
                        //displayBusyIndicator();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        //hideBusyIndicator();
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        console.log('complete');
                        //hideBusyIndicator();
                    }
                });
           
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: What is your 'result' type in UploadCallingDocument ?

Comment: yes here it is , FileContentResult , with result type is byte[] array                                        in the code                                                                                                               return File(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Summarized_KeepAndShare_File.xlsx");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the UploadCallingDocument method, the FileContentResult is returned to the Ajax success function, the download was unsuccessful because you did not operate in success. So I add an action to download,  use  `window.location` to redirect to the `Download` action in controller.

Below code I use serialize an object of type 'System.Byte[]',so I first
Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package.
Then in ConfigureServices() add a call to AddNewtonsoftJson().

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

In your Controller, change your code like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadCallingDocument(UploadCallingViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                FormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files as FormFileCollection;
                {
                    IFormFile file = files[0];
                    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                        TempData["file"]  = await importExportFileManager.KeepAndShareFileAsync(stream);
                        return Ok();
                    }

                            
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //to create error notification
            }
            return RedirectToAction("UploadCalling");
        }
       [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult Download()
        {
            byte[] data = TempData["file"] as byte[];
            return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Summarized_KeepAndShare_File.xlsx");
                    
        }
```

In your ajax success, change your code like below:

```
success: function (data) {
                window.location = '/yourcontrollername/Download';
            }
```

Result:
[image]